# PyCharm unittest: "Failed to import test module" caused by "loadTestsFromName" in a symlink environment

Tags: pycharm, symlink, python-unittest

I tried to run my unittests in PyCharm where my workspace is a symlink (via `ln -s`). I kept getting the following output:

```
Testing started at 17:50 ...
<HOME>/.virtualenvs/venv/bin/python <PYCHARM>/helpers/pycharm/_jb_unittest_runner.py --path <PROJECT_ACTUAL_DIR>/module/test_module.py
Launching unittests with arguments python -m unittest <PROJECT_LINKED_DIR>/module/module_test.py in <PROJECT_ACTUAL_DIR>/module

Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/case.py", line 58, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/case.py", line 600, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/loader.py", line 34, in testFailure
    raise self._exception
ImportError: Failed to import test module: <PROJECT_LINKED_DIR>/module/test_module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/loader.py", line 153, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
ImportError: No module named '<PROJECT_LINKED_DIR>/module/test_module'
```

Can anybody give me a good solution for this problem? I want to keep my symlink structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that the problem really is the symlink structure. In particular running unittest using the virtual path fails:

```
python -m unittest <PROJECT_LINKED_DIR>/module/module_test.py
```

while using the actual directory works:

```
python -m unittest <PROJECT_ACTUAL_DIR>/module/module_test.py
```

The PyCharm config however faithfully tries to use the  since this is where I opened the project from (see "Run->Edit Configurations...").

Unfortunately, I was not able to come up with general solution for this issue. I only found a workaround when running tests.

**Workaround**:
Interestingly enough, for the PyCharm IDE, running the whole file `test_module.py` raises the exception mentioned above, running test classes and tests themselves works just fine. So try not to click in the header of your file `test_module.py` when initializing your test (e.g., by hitting STRG+SHIFT+F10). Instead focus on the class name or the signature of a test method.